# Trace of "quadratic form"-like expression involving orthonormal vector fields and their Jacobian

Tags: vector-analysis, orthonormal, jacobian

Let $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^D, \mathbb{R}^K)$ be a smooth function whose Jacobian matrix $Df$ has full rank on $M=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^D: f(x)=\vec{0}\}$. We take the convention that the rows of the Jacobian are the transposes of the gradients of the components of $f$.
Let $N(x)$ be the matrix obtained by orthonormalizing *the rows of* of $Df(x)$, so that $N(x)N(x)^T=I_{K\times K}$.

**Question**: Is it always true that $\operatorname{Tr}(N D[n_r] N^T)=0$?

When $K=1$, we can prove this is indeed true. In this case, we have $n=\nabla f/\|\nabla f\|$ and we just have to show $n^T D[n]n=0$. It is relatively straightforward to show that
$$D[n]n = \frac{1}{\|\nabla f\|} (\nabla^2 f) n- \frac{1}{\|\nabla f\|}\left(n^T (\nabla^2 f)n\right)n.$$
Multiplying this on the right by $n^T$ gives
$$n^T D[n]n = \frac{1}{\|\nabla f\|} n^T(\nabla^2 f) n- \frac{1}{\|\nabla f\|}n^T\left(n^T (\nabla^2 f)n\right)n.$$
$$=:\frac{1}{\|\nabla f\|} v- \frac{1}{\|\nabla f\|}n^Tvn.$$
where we have written $v:=n^T(\nabla^2 f)n$ for convenience. Now, $v$ is just a scalar, so we can rewrite the second term as
$$\frac{1}{\|\nabla \|} vn^T n = \frac{v}{\|\nabla f\|},$$
since $n^Tn=1$ due to $n$ being a unit-normal vector. Thus we obtain
$$n^T D[n]n = \frac{1}{\|\nabla f\|} v - \frac{1}{\|\nabla f\|} v=0,$$
as claimed.

When $K>1$, it is a lot more difficult to follow one's nose here...

**Update 8/31/2023**
Fix $r$ and $r'$ in $\{1,2,\dotsc, K\}$. Using linearity and product rule, we can show that, since $n_r^Tn_{r'} = \delta_{rr'}$
$$D[n_r]^Tn_{r'}=-D[n_{r'}]^Tn_r,$$
hence $D[n_r]^T n_r = \vec{0}$. It follows that
$$(ND[n_r]N^T)_{ij} = -n_r^T D[n_i]n_j,$$
hence
$$\operatorname{Tr}(ND[n_r]N^T) = -\sum_{j=1}^K n_r^T D[n_j]n_j$$
$$=-\sum_{j\neq r} n_r^T D[n_j]n_j,$$
since $D[n_r]^T n_r=\vec{0}$, hence we know $n_r^T D[n_r]n_r = (D[n_r]^T n_r)^T n_r = \vec{0}^T n_r = 0$. But it is difficult for me to see anything else.

**Update 9/1/2023**
Let's assume there exists a vector $v(x)$ such that
$$P(x)v(x) = \sum_{k=1}^K D[n_k(x)]n_k(x),$$
where $P(x)=I-N(x)^T N(x)$ is the orthogonal projection onto $T_xM$ the tangent space of $M$ at $x$. Then from the previous update, we have with $r=i$ and $r'=k$,
$$n_k^TD[n_i] = -n_i^T D[n_k]$$
hence multiplying on the right by $n_k$ gives
$$n_k^T D[n_i] n_k = -n_i^T D[n_k]n_k,$$
so that summing from $k=1$ to $K$ gives
$$\operatorname{Tr}(N D[n_i] N^T) = -n_i^T \left(\sum_{k=1}^K D[n_k]n_k\right)$$
$$ = -n_i^T Pv,$$
but $Pv$ lies in $T_xM$ and obviously $n_i \perp u$ for any $u\in T_xM$. Thus $-n_i^T Pv = 0$ hence this trace term is zero,
$$\operatorname{Tr}(ND[n_i]N^T)=0,$$
for $i=1,2,\dotsc, K$.

So, now my questions are:

1. taking the assumption for granted, is this argument sound and valid?
2. Is the assumption true? I have essentially already asked it in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4646441/solving-a-gradient-equation-involving-jacobian-of-orthonormal-vectors) and just made the connection today between the two. There $v=\nabla \log p$ where $p$ solves the steady-state Fokker-Planck equation of the process satisfying $dX_t = P(X_t)\circ dB_t$. I have proven it in the case $K=1$, in which then $p$ is proportional to $\|\nabla f\|$.